# how to access a character in an array of strings in c

Tags: arrays, c, char, c-strings, toupper

I have been trying to uppercase the first letter of a string which is inside an array of strings I tried a lot of methods but none of them worked here is my code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 int nw=0;
 char words[30][50];
 int main(){
 printf("enter your words when you finish write b\n");
 do{
 nw++;
 scanf("%s",&words[nw]);
 }while(strcmp(&words[nw],"b")!=0);
 printf("%s",toupper(&words[1][0]));
 }
```

what should I do please help

Comment: You should indent your code properly.

Comment: Arrays start at index 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters you need to include headers `<ctype.h>` and `<string.h>`

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
```

There is no great sense to declare these variables

```
int nw=0;
char words[30][50];
```

in the file scope. They could be declared in `main`.

Instead of this call

```
scanf("%s",&words[nw]);
```

you have to write at least

```
scanf("%s", words[nw]);
```

The condition in the do-while statement should look like

```
while( nw < 30 && strcmp(words[nw],"b") != 0 );
```

And instead of this call'

```
printf("%s",toupper(&words[1][0]));
```

you should write

```
words[1][0] = toupper( ( unsigned char )words[1][0] );
printf( "%s", words[1] );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char words[30][50] =
    {
        "hello", "world!"
    };
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; words[i][0] != '\0'; i++ )
    {
        words[i][0] = toupper( ( unsigned char )words[i][0] );
        printf( "%s ", words[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello World!
```